# How to marshal int* in C#?

Tags: .net, marshalling, intptr

I would like to call this method in unmanaged library:

```
void __stdcall GetConstraints(

  unsigned int* puiMaxWidth,

  unsigned int* puiMaxHeight,

  unsigned int* puiMaxBoxes

);
```

My solution:

- Delegate definition:

  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  private delegate void GetConstraintsDel(UIntPtr puiMaxWidth, UIntPtr puiMaxHeight, UIntPtr puiMaxBoxes);
- The call of the method:

  ```
  // PLUGIN NAME
  GetConstraintsDel getConstraints = (GetConstraintsDel)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(GetConstraintsDel));

   uint maxWidth, maxHeight, maxBoxes;

   unsafe
   {
      UIntPtr a = new UIntPtr(&maxWidth);
      UIntPtr b = new UIntPtr(&maxHeight);
      UIntPtr c = new UIntPtr(&maxBoxes);
      getConstraints(a, b, c);
   }
  ```

It works but I have to allow "unsafe" flag. Is there a solution without unsafe code? Or is this solution ok? I don't quite understand the implications of setting the project with unsafe flag.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I believe it should work as it is (minus the address-of operators) without the unsafe block...

Comment: It doesn't work. The constructor of UIntPtr takes as parameter the pointer address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just out uint?

ie:

```
HRESULT GetTypeDefProps (
   [in]  mdTypeDef   td,
   [out] LPWSTR      szTypeDef,
   [in]  ULONG       cchTypeDef,
   [out] ULONG       *pchTypeDef,
   [out] DWORD       *pdwTypeDefFlags,
   [out] mdToken     *ptkExtends
);
```

works fine with:

```
uint GetTypeDefProps
(
  uint td, 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=2)]char[] szTypeDef, 
  uint cchTypeDef, 
  out uint pchTypeDef, 
  out uint pdwTypeDefFlags, 
  out uint ptknds
 );
```

Sample use;

```
char[] SzTypeDef;
uint CchTypeDef;
uint PchMember;
IntPtr PpvSigBlob;
uint PbSigBlob;

  SzTypeDef= new char[500];
  CchTypeDef= (uint)SzTypeDef.Length;

ResPT= 
  MetaDataImport.GetTypeDefProps
  (
    td, 
    SzTypeDef, 
    CchTypeDef, 
    out pchTypeDef, 
    out pdwTypeDefFlags,
    out ptkExtends
  );
```